Using Direct Query, want to create Calculated Column
to_char(trunc([SQL1].[time_in_sec]/3600), 'FM9999999900')|| ':' || to_char(trunc(mod([SQL1].[time_in_sec]  ,3600)/60), 'FM00')     || ':' || to_char(mod([SQL1].[time_in_sec]  ,60), 'FM00')

I am looking to covert this SQL query into a calculated column in Power BI. Since this is a direct query, I can not use DAX functions like FORMAT or conditionals like IF. Can anyone suggest an alternative?
I have tried Power BI, calculated column
time = 
VAR hh = TRUNC(([QUEUE_TIME_QTY])/3600)
VAR mm =TRUNC(MOD([QUEUE_TIME_QTY],3600)/60)
VAR ss = MOD([QUEUE_TIME_QTY],60)
return TIME(hh,mm,ss)

This gives me ORA-00936 error in Power BI.
